# How to install latest version of git on CentOS 8.x/7.x/6.x

Tags: linux, git, installation, centos, yum

I used the usual:

```
yum install git
```

It did not install the latest version of git on my CentOS 6. How can I update to the latest version of git for CentOS 6? The solution can be applicable to newer versions of CentOS such as CentOS 7.

Comment: Yes, it is. It's entirely within bounds to ask a question and answer it when it's useful info that hasn't been addressed.

Comment: Without using external repos to upgrade Git, you can try to use `yum shell` commands. Here's how I've upgraded **from git 1.8 to git 2.24**: https://serverfault.com/a/1045216/91648

Answer (score 403, accepted):

You can use WANDisco's CentOS repository to install Git 2.x: for [CentOS 6](http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/git/x86_64/), for [CentOS 7](http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/7/git/x86_64/)

1. Install WANDisco repo package:

   ```
   yum install http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/git/x86_64/wandisco-git-release-6-1.noarch.rpm
   - or -
   yum install http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/7/git/x86_64/wandisco-git-release-7-1.noarch.rpm
   - or -
   yum install http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/7/git/x86_64/wandisco-git-release-7-2.noarch.rpm
   ```
2. Install the latest version of Git 2.x:

   ```
   yum install git
   ```
3. Verify the version of Git that was installed:

   ```
   git --version
   ```

As of 02 Mar. 2020, the latest available version from WANDisco is **2.22.0**.

Comment: This answer must be applied. Already applied answer with `--disablerepo=base,updates` doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Kirby Make sure that `wandisco-git.repo` exists in `/etc/yum.repos.d` and has `enabled=1` in it.

Comment: @JosephLeedy, thanks for the answer. Maybe it can fix. I'd like to avoid editing files. Only commands. I use vagrant for VM and those commands don't work by default. I need to wake up vm and it should work. If you know the command which could update this file, I would appreciate it. I'm not talking about some bash commands. :)

Comment: Thank you. I've been struggling with updating git on an Oracle Linux 6 box. This was the silver bullet.

Comment: wandisco also provides binaries for centos5: http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/5/git/x86_64/  Which nobody should really be using at this point, but if you are, there's an enabler for you.

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. Much simpler than the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you. I tried other methods from Digital Ocean, qiita.com, blacksaildivision.com. They did not work. But your instruction is really worked. But how can I install the **newest version**? (now is **2.17**)

Comment: I tried to pull the source down and make the binary myself but failed. Thanks for keeping it simple for the newbs!

Comment: july 2018 :
`sudo yum install http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/7/git/x86_64/wandisco-git-release-7-2.noarch.rpm`

Comment: As of Feb 2019, this repo seems to have stopped getting updates: latest git is v2.20.1 but the repo has only v2.18.0

Comment: the pgp key isn't available via https, can anyone else verify it?

Comment: This must be the accepted answer. Worked for me on Centos 6.9. Thank u so much ! :)

Comment: @IanB the updates seemed to have resumed as of this writing; just used the `wandisco-git-release-7-2.noarch.rpm` instance and git v2.22.0 was installed

Comment: I've try the `wandisco-git-release-7-2.noarch.rpm`, (git 1.8 previously installed, now i want to upgrade it). Then `yum update git`, I got an error `Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: WANdisco-git`, The same error occur when I run `yum history undo`  to undo wanDisco install. Now i'm stuck, in production environment... Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: For their PGP key fingerprint, I got `69c1 be83 da54 cbed 6889 72f8 e9f0 e922 3bbf 077a`

Comment: As of 2021.10.26 WANdisco repo provides git v2.31.1 for both CentOS 6 and CentOS 7. IUS repo (recommended in other answer) provides git v2.24 only for CentOS 7, it's CentOS 6 repo seems to be discontinued.

Answer (score 134):

Having a look at the blog [here](http://akyl.net/how-install-latest-version-git-centos-6x) I found the solution in one of the comments. Make sure you got the `rpmforge` repository added to your CentOS yum and just run the flowing command:

```
yum --disablerepo=base,updates --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras install git
```

If you already have git installed then use:

```
yum --disablerepo=base,updates --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras update git
```

Related question(s):

1. [Facing issues while upgrading git to latest version on CentOS 6.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841562/facing-issues-while-upgrading-git-to-latest-version-on-centos-6-4)

#### Note update:

Thanks to Anthony Hatzopoulos, for `git v1.8x` you'll need to use git18 as in:

```
yum --disablerepo=base,updates --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras install git18
```

#### Note update 2:

Also thanks to  @Axlrod for the below hint and @Hiphip for the feedback:

Change the `rpmforge.repo` file to have `rpmforge-extras` to enabled,
`yum update git`. Otherwise it complained about dependency problems.

#### Note update 3:

> Installing a specific version of git say 2.x
>   I found this nice and easy-to-follow guide on how to download the GIT source and compile it yourself (and install it). If the accepted answer does not give you the version you want, try the following instructions:

http://tecadmin.net/install-git-2-0-on-centos-rhel-fedora/

(And pasted/reformatted from above source in case it is removed later)

**Step 1:** Install Required Packages

Firstly we need to make sure that we have installed required packages on your system. Use following command to install required packages before compiling Git source.

```
# yum install curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel
# yum install  gcc perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker
```

**Step 2:** Uninstall old Git RPM

Now remove any prior installation of Git through RPM file or Yum package manager. If your older version is also compiled through source, then skip this step.

```
# yum remove git
```

**Step 3:** Download and Compile Git Source

Download git source code from kernel git or simply use following command to download Git 2.0.4.

```
# cd /usr/src
# wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.0.4.tar.gz
# tar xzf git-2.0.4.tar.gz
```

After downloading and extracting Git source code, Use following command to compile source code.

```
# cd git-2.0.4
# make prefix=/usr/local/git all
# make prefix=/usr/local/git install
#
# echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin' >> /etc/bashrc
#  or
# echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin' > /etc/profile.d/git.sh
#
# source /etc/bashrc
```

> HINT 1: 
>   Updated method of adding compiled git bin directory to bashrc. Because `echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin" >> /etc/bashrc` used "" instead of '', it would expand the current session's value for $PATH instead of keeping it as a variable, and could adversely affect the entire system. At the minimum, it should use '' instead of "" and should really be a separate script in `/etc/profile.d/`
>
> HINT 2 (@DJB):
>   `/usr/local/git/bin` before `$PATH`, since the older version of git was already on $PATH: `export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH`

**Step 4.** Check Git Version

One completion of above steps, you have successfully install Git in your system. Let use following command to check git version

```
# git --version

git version 2.0.4
```

I also wanted to add that the "Getting Started" guide at the GIT website also includes instructions on how to download and compile it yourself:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Comment: This only got me git v1.7x. For git v1.8x you'll need to use `git18` as in `yum --disablerepo=base,updates --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras install git18`

Comment: didn't work for me, I had to change the rpmforge.repo file to have rpmforge-extras to enabled, and then do yum update git. Otherwise it complained about dependency problems. (since it needed packages from base)

Comment: Error getting repository data for rpmforge-extras, repository not found - 1st cmd on cent6.6

Comment: Running `yum --disablerepo=base,updates --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras list | grep git` only shows Git 1.7.12 for me on Centos 6.6. Perhaps they've removed "git18"?

Comment: What was the @Keith answer?  Now lost.  Would have been safer to edit your answer & paste it in.

Comment: @EdRandall, the problem was -Keith changed his profile name. To avoid future confusions I added his answer in Update 4 in my answer.

Comment: Hm, this solution doesn't work for me. `Error getting repository data for rpmforge-extras, repository not found`. CentOS 6.7. This way from another post always works. `yum install http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/git/x86_64/wandisco-git-release-6-1.noarch.rpm && yum install git`

Comment: https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge
RPMForge/RepoForge is a dead project. It is not maintained. DO NOT USE.

Comment: When building from source, I needed to put `/usr/local/git/bin` **before** `$PATH`, since the older version of `git` was already on `$PATH`: `export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 109):

Rackspace maintains the [ius repository](https://repo.ius.io/), which contains a reasonably up-to-date git, but the stock git has to first be removed.

CentOS 6 or 7 instructions (run as root or with sudo):

```sh
# retrieve and check CENTOS_MAIN_VERSION (6 or 7):
CENTOS_MAIN_VERSION=$(cat /etc/centos-release | awk -F 'release[ ]*' '{print $2}' | awk -F '.' '{print $1}')
echo $CENTOS_MAIN_VERSION
# output should be "6" or "7"

# Install IUS Repo and Epel-Release:
yum install -y https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el${CENTOS_MAIN_VERSION}.rpm
yum install -y epel-release 

# re-install git:
yum erase -y git*
yum install -y git-core

# check version:
git --version
# output: git version 2.24.3
```

Note: `git-all` instead of `git-core` often installs an old version. Try e.g. `git224-all` instead.

The script is tested on a CentOS 7 docker image (`7e6257c9f8d8`) and on a CentOS 6 docker image (`d0957ffdf8a2`).

Comment: Nice! Those rpmforge compile instructions did not work -- `Can't locate ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm in @INC`

Comment: This one worked for me today for the most recent centos, the others were outdated.

Comment: This is the only method on this page that I've tried (as of 7 September 2018) that ensures an up-to-date 2.x git for CentOS *and* also ensures a compiled `git-credential-libsecret` is installed, which is the safest os-native means for storing git credentials, e.g. for http[s] URLs.  The currently accepted answer at the time of writing (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21820716/407170) does not do these things and requires you to compile yourself.

Comment: If you want to automate this using Ansible, I recommend checking out https://github.com/iuscommunity/automation-examples/blob/0568e34b2f689c23e26ccc0e0218c01d7ae11e02/enable-ius.yml (or https://github.com/iuscommunity/automation-examples for other solutions)

Answer (score 90):

I found this nice and easy-to-follow guide on how to download the GIT source and compile it yourself (and install it). If the accepted answer does not give you the version you want, try the following instructions:

http://tecadmin.net/install-git-2-0-on-centos-rhel-fedora/

(And pasted/reformatted from above source in case it is removed later)

**Step 1:** Install Required Packages

Firstly we need to make sure that we have installed required packages on your system. Use following command to install required packages before compiling Git source.

```
# yum install curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel
# yum install  gcc perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker
```

**Step 2:** Uninstall old Git RPM

Now remove any prior installation of Git through RPM file or Yum package manager. If your older version is also compiled through source, then skip this step.

```
# yum remove git
```

**Step 3:** Download and Compile Git Source

Download git source code from kernel git or simply use following command to download Git 2.5.3.

```
# cd /usr/src
# wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.5.3.tar.gz
# tar xzf git-2.5.3.tar.gz
```

After downloading and extracting Git source code, Use following command to compile source code.

```
# cd git-2.5.3
# make prefix=/usr/local/git all
# make prefix=/usr/local/git install
# echo 'pathmunge /usr/local/git/bin/' > /etc/profile.d/git.sh 
# chmod +x /etc/profile.d/git.sh
# source /etc/bashrc
```

**Step 4.** Check Git Version

On completion of above steps, you have successfully install Git in your system. Use the following command to check the git version

```
# git --version

git version 2.5.3
```

I also wanted to add that the "Getting Started" guide at the GIT website also includes instructions on how to download and compile it yourself:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Comment: Re Step 3. setting the path, I found this (http://serverfault.com/a/303824)  works better:  

# echo 'pathmunge /usr/local/git/bin/' > /etc/profile.d/git.sh
# chmod +x /etc/profile.d/git.sh

Comment: I tried on Centos 6.5 and tried latest (today) GIT version 2.5.3, and works like a charm. `wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.5.3.tar.gz`

Comment: Working with 2.7.4 and CentOS 6.5 - Thanks

Comment: This allowed me to install 2.10.1 to keep parity with my git local client. Awesome set of instructions.

Comment: Worked for me on Centos 6.8 8/21/17.

Comment: If you still find that git is not installed then it might be due to pathmunge. You can use following commands to add git in your environment. 

`echo "export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH" >> /etc/bashrc`
and then 
`source /etc/bashrc`

Comment: @mshakeel What would the advantage of your suggestion be over "echo 'pathmunge /usr/local/git/bin/' > /etc/profile.d/git.sh "? I imagine you had some problem using that, so I am just curious about what it was.

Comment: Pytry: pathmunge was not working on my instance. I was getting git is not working.

Comment: @AlphaOF Glad to help. There are several great answers to this question, so I suggest looking into all of them to see what really works best for you.

Comment: It worked for me on CentOS 7 with `git-2.9.5.tar.gz`. It's worth to know that one should open a new terminal, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27557519/1883256).

Comment: Notice: `yum install curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel` aded a dependency on git. I had to `yum remove git` after git was compiled and installed from sources. I'm on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 10):

My personal preference is to build rpm packages for CentOS when installing non-standard software and replacing distributed components.  For this I recommend that you use Mock to create a clean build environment.

The procedure is:

1. Obtain the source RPMS or a suitable SPEC file and pristine source tarball.  In this case one may find source RPM packages for git2X for CentOS-6 at:  `http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/archive/CentOS/6/SRPMS/`. Packages for other CentOS releases are also available.
2. Install the necessary support software:

   ```
   yum install epel-release  # you need this for mock
   yum install rpm-build
   yum install redhat-rpm-config
   yum install rpmdevtools
   yum install mock
   ```
3. Add a rpm build user account (*do not build as root or as a real user - security issues **will** come back to bite you*).

   ```
   sudo adduser builder --home-dir /home/builder \
   --create-home --user-group --groups mock \
   --shell /bin/bash --comment "rpm package builder"
   ```
4. Next we need a build environment.

   ```
   su -l builder
   rpmdev-setuptree
   ```

   This produces the following directory structure:

   ```
   ~
   └── rpmbuild
       ├── BUILD
       ├── RPMS
       ├── SOURCES
       ├── SPECS
       └── SRPMS
   ```
5. We are using a prepared SRPMS so the SOURCES tarballs can be ignored for this case and we can go direct to SRPMS.

   ```
   wget http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/archive/CentOS/6/SRPMS/git2u-2.5.3-1.ius.centos6.src.rpm \
   -O ~/rpmbuild/SRPMS/git2u-2.5.3-1.ius.centos6.src.rpm
   ```
6. Configure mock (as root)

   ```
   cd /etc/mock
   rm default.cfg
   ln -s epel-6-x86_64.cfg default.cfg
   vim default.cfg
   ```

   Disable the `beta` repos. Enable the `base` and `update` repos.
7. Initialize the build tree (/var/lib/mock is default)

   ```
   mock --init
   ```
8. If we were building from SOURCES then this is where we would employ the SPEC file and use `mock --buildsrpm . . .`.  But in this case we go directly to the binary build step:

   ```
   mock --no-clean --rebuild ~/rpmbuild/SRPMS/git2u-2.5.3-1.ius.centos6.src.rpm
   ```

   This will resolve the build dependencies and download them (about 95 or so packages) into the clean build root. It will then extract the sources and build the binary from the provided SRPM and leave it in `/var/lib/mock/epel-6-x86_64/result`; or in whatever custom build root location and architecture you provided.  It will take a long time. There is a lot to this package; particularly documentation.
9. If all goes well then you should end up with a suit of RPM packages suitable for installation in place of the distro version.  This is what I ended up with:

   ```
   ll /var/lib/mock/epel-6-x86_64/result
   total 34996
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock   448455 Oct 30 10:09 build.log
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock    52464 Oct 30 10:09 emacs-git2u-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.noarch.rpm
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock    47228 Oct 30 10:09 emacs-git2u-el-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.noarch.rpm
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock  8474478 Oct 30 09:57 git2u-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.src.rpm
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock  8877584 Oct 30 10:09 git2u-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock    27284 Oct 30 10:09 git2u-all-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.noarch.rpm
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock    27800 Oct 30 10:09 git2u-bzr-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.noarch.rpm
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock   112564 Oct 30 10:09 git2u-cvs-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.noarch.rpm
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock   436176 Oct 30 10:09 git2u-daemon-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock 15858600 Oct 30 10:09 git2u-debuginfo-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock    60556 Oct 30 10:09 git2u-email-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.noarch.rpm
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock   274888 Oct 30 10:09 git2u-gui-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.noarch.rpm
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock    79176 Oct 30 10:09 git2u-p4-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.noarch.rpm
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock   483132 Oct 30 10:09 git2u-svn-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock   173732 Oct 30 10:09 gitk2u-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.noarch.rpm
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock   115692 Oct 30 10:09 gitweb2u-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.noarch.rpm
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock    57196 Oct 30 10:09 perl-Git2u-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.noarch.rpm
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock    89900 Oct 30 10:09 perl-Git2u-SVN-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.noarch.rpm
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock   101026 Oct 30 10:09 root.log
   -rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb mock      980 Oct 30 10:09 state.log
   ```
10. Install using yum or rpm.

    You will require `git2u-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm` at a minimum and such additional support packages as it requires (`perl-Git2u-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.noarch.rpm`) or you desire.

    This build has a cyclic dependency: `git2u-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm` depends upon `perl-Git2u-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.noarch.rpm` and `perl-Git2u-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.noarch.rpm` depends upon `git2u-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm`. A straight install with `rpm` will thus fail.

    There are two ways of dealing with it:

    - Install both at the same time via yum:

      ```
      yum localinstall \
        git2u-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm \
        perl-Git2u-2.5.3-1.ius.el6.noarch.rpm`
      ```
    - Setup a local yum repo.

      I am including my `LocalFile.repo` file below as it contains instructions on how to do this and provides the necessary repo file at the same time.

```
cat /etc/yum.repos.d/LocalFile.repo
# LocalFile.repo
#
#  This repo is used with a local filesystem repo.
#
# To use this repo place the rpm package in /root/RPMS/yum.repo/Packages.
# Then run: createrepo --database --update /root/RPMS/yum.repo.
#
# To use:
#  yum --enablerepo=localfile [command]
#  
# or to use only ONLY this repo, do this:
#
#  yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=localfile [command]

[localfile]
baseurl=file:///root/RPMS/yum.repo
name=CentOS-$releasever - Local Filesystem repo

# Before persistently enabling this repo see the priority note below.
enabled=0
gpgcheck=0

# When this repo is enabled all packages in repos with priority>5
# will not be updated even when they have a more recent version.
# Be careful with this.
priority=5
```

You also may be required to manually pre-install additional dependency packages such as `perl-TermReadKey` available from the usual repositories.

Comment: If you aren't going to be editing the spec file, why not just use the IUS binary packages directly?

Answer (score 5):

To build and install modern Git on CentOS 6:

```
yum install -y curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel gcc perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker
export GIT_VERSION=2.6.4
mkdir /root/git
cd /root/git
wget "https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-${GIT_VERSION}.tar.gz"
tar xvzf "git-${GIT_VERSION}.tar.gz"
cd git-${GIT_VERSION}
make prefix=/usr/local all
make prefix=/usr/local install
yum remove -y git
git --version # should be GIT_VERSION
```

Answer (score 5):

## Build latest version of `git` on Centos 6/7

### Preparing system to building rpms

1. Install epel:

   For EL6, use:

   ```
   sudo yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
   ```

   For EL7, use:

   ```
   sudo yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
   ```
2. Install `fedpkg`:

   ```
   sudo yum install fedpkg
   ```
3. Add yourself into group mock (you might need to re-login to server after this change):

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G mock $USER
   ```

### Download `git`

1. Download `git` sources:

   ```
   fedpkg clone -a git && cd git
   fedpkg sources
   ```
2. Verify sources:

   ```
   sha512sum -c sources
   ```

### Build rpm

1. Create srmp. Use `el6` for RHEL6, `el7` for RHEL7.

   ```
   fedpkg --dist el7 srpm
   ```
2. Build package in mock:

   ```
   mock -r epel-7-x86_64 git-2.16.0-1.el7.src.rpm
   ```
3. Install latest version of `git` rpm from `/var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64/result/`. Note, you might need to uninstall existing version of the git from your system first.

This instruction is based on [the mailing list post by Todd Zullinger](https://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg223958.html).

Comment: Great answer. Keep it under package management. Much better than using unofficial repos or installing from source. I've always downloaded the src package from the Fedora package site through the browser, but this is a much cleaner solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

[as git says](https://git-scm.com/download/linux):

> RHEL and derivatives typically ship older versions of git. You can
>   download a tarball and build from source, or use a 3rd-party
>   repository such as the IUS Community Project to obtain a more recent
>   version of git.

there  is good tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-centos-7).
in my case (Centos7 server) after install had to logout and login again.

Answer (score 4):

[This guide](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-latest-version-of-git-git-2-x-on-centos-7/) worked:

```
# hostnamectl
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
# git --version
git version 1.8.3.1
# sudo yum remove git*
# sudo yum -y install https://packages.endpointdev.com/rhel/7/os/x86_64/endpoint-repo.x86_64.rpm
# sudo yum install git
# git --version
git version 2.24.1
```

Comment: For anyone that doesn't already have the Endpoint repo trusted on their machine, I ran: curl -LO 'https://packages.endpoint.com/endpoint-rpmsign-7.pub', 
rpm --import endpoint-rpmsign-7.pub, 
rpm -qi gpg-pubkey-703df089 | gpg --with-fingerprint

Comment: For anyone else using the End Point package repository, note that it has moved and you can now get the current repo RPM URLs at: https://packages.endpointdev.com/

It also has Git 2.30.1 at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my method to install git on centos 6.

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo yum install zlib-devel perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker asciidoc xmlto openssl-devel curl-devel
sudo yum install wget
cd ~
wget -O git.zip https://github.com/git/git/archive/v2.7.2.zip
unzip git.zip
cd git-2.7.2
make configure
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make all doc
sudo make install install-doc install-html
```

Comment: In my experience (centos 6.7), you should also also `yum install libcurl-devel`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a roundabout answer here. I was struggling to install git on an RHEL 6.0 Amazon instance, and what ended up saving me was ... conda, as in Ana*conda* Python.

I installed conda on the command line from the [archives](https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/) (code modeled after [this](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/help/silent.html)):

```
wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda2-4.2.12-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh
bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda
export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
```

and then ran

```
conda install git
```

and a relatively recent version git was installed. Today is 12/26/2016 and the version is 2.9.3.

Answer (score 1):

This may be irrelevant. It is for people don't want build the latest git on the host meanwhile they still can get the latest git.

I think most people don't like building the latest git on CentOS because the dependencies will contaminate the host and you have to run lots of commands. Therefore, I have an idea which is building git inside the Docker container and then install the executable via the docker volume mount. After that, you can delete the image and container.

Yes, the downside is you have to install docker. But the least dependencies are introduced to the host and you don't have to install other yum repo.

Here is my repository. https://github.com/wood1986/docker-library/tree/master/git

Answer (score 0):

If git already installed first remove old git

```
sudo yum remove git*
```

And install latest version of git

```
yum install -y git-core
```

Check Version
git --version

bingo!!

Comment: With `yum install -y git2u`, I got the error message `No package git2u available.`. However, the command `yum install -y git-core` has successfully installed git version 2.24.3. Also `yum install -y git224` leads to the desired result. Note, that removing existing git installations is needed to avoid possible conflicts. Note also that `yum install -y git` or `yum install -y git-all` might install an older version from existing repos (tested in the current centos:7 docker image; there, git version 1.8.3.1 is installed, currently).

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is the Steps to upgrade git on CentOS 7 which I have followed

```
$ sudo yum list git*

Installed Packages
git.x86_64                                                                                            1.8.3.1-20.el7                                                                                     @base  
Available Packages  
git.x86_64          1.8.3.1-25.el7_9     updates 
git-svn.x86_64      1.8.3.1-25.el7_9     updates  
git236.x86_64       2.36.6-1.el7.ius     ius    
git236-all.noarch   2.36.6-1.el7.ius     ius    
git236-core.x86_64  2.36.6-1.el7.ius     ius
```

Choose from above git pkg list e.g git236

```
$ sudo yum shell
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
> erase git
> install git236
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: linux.mirrors.es.net
 * epel: mirrors.sonic.net
 * extras: centos-distro.cavecreek.net
 * updates: mirror.team-cymru.com
> run
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.8.3.1-20.el7 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: git = 1.8.3.1-20.el7 for package: perl-Git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.noarch
---> Package git236.x86_64 0:2.36.6-1.el7.ius will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 2.36.6-1.el7.ius for package: git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: git-core-doc = 2.36.6-1.el7.ius for package: git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: git-core = 2.36.6-1.el7.ius for package: git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git::I18N) for package: git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git236-core.x86_64 0:2.36.6-1.el7.ius will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre2-8.so.0()(64bit) for package: git236-core-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64
---> Package git236-core-doc.noarch 0:2.36.6-1.el7.ius will be installed
---> Package git236-perl-Git.noarch 0:2.36.6-1.el7.ius will be installed
---> Package perl-Git.noarch 0:1.8.3.1-20.el7 will be erased
--> Running transaction check
---> Package pcre2.x86_64 0:10.23-2.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                               Arch                                         Version                                                   Repository                                   Size
================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 git236                                                x86_64                                       2.36.6-1.el7.ius                                          ius                                          71 k
Removing:
 git                                                   x86_64                                       1.8.3.1-20.el7                                            @base                                        22 M
Installing for dependencies:
 git236-core                                           x86_64                                       2.36.6-1.el7.ius                                          ius                                         6.9 M
 git236-core-doc                                       noarch                                       2.36.6-1.el7.ius                                          ius                                         2.8 M
 git236-perl-Git                                       noarch                                       2.36.6-1.el7.ius                                          ius                                          46 k
 pcre2                                                 x86_64                                       10.23-2.el7                                               base                                        201 k
Removing for dependencies:
 perl-Git                                              noarch                                       1.8.3.1-20.el7                                            @base                                        57 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+4 Dependent packages)
Remove   1 Package (+1 Dependent package)

Total download size: 9.9 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/ius/packages/git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 4b274df2: NOKEY                                      ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Public key for git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64.rpm is not installed
(1/5): git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                |  71 kB  00:00:00     
(2/5): git236-core-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                           | 6.9 MB  00:00:00     
(3/5): git236-core-doc-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                                       | 2.8 MB  00:00:00     
(4/5): git236-perl-Git-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                                       |  46 kB  00:00:00     
(5/5): pcre2-10.23-2.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                      | 201 kB  00:00:00     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                                                           9.2 MB/s | 9.9 MB  00:00:01     
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-IUS-7
Importing GPG key 0x4B274DF2:
 Userid     : "IUS (7) <dev@ius.io>"
 Fingerprint: c958 7a09 a11f d706 4f0c a0f4 e558 0725 4b27 4df2
 Package    : ius-release-2-1.el7.ius.noarch (installed)
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-IUS-7
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : pcre2-10.23-2.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                     1/7 
  Installing : git236-core-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64                                                                                                                                                          2/7 
  Installing : git236-core-doc-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.noarch                                                                                                                                                      3/7 
  Installing : git236-perl-Git-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.noarch                                                                                                                                                      4/7 
  Installing : git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64                                                                                                                                                               5/7 
  Erasing    : perl-Git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.noarch                                                                                                                                                               6/7 
  Erasing    : git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                    7/7 
  Verifying  : pcre2-10.23-2.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                     1/7 
  Verifying  : git236-core-doc-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.noarch                                                                                                                                                      2/7 
  Verifying  : git236-core-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64                                                                                                                                                          3/7 
  Verifying  : git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64                                                                                                                                                               4/7 
  Verifying  : git236-perl-Git-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.noarch                                                                                                                                                      5/7 
  Verifying  : git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                    6/7 
  Verifying  : perl-Git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.noarch                                                                                                                                                               7/7 

Removed:
  git.x86_64 0:1.8.3.1-20.el7                                                                                                                                                                                   

Dependency Removed:
  perl-Git.noarch 0:1.8.3.1-20.el7                                                                                                                                                                              

Installed:
  git236.x86_64 0:2.36.6-1.el7.ius                                                                                                                                                                              

Dependency Installed:
  git236-core.x86_64 0:2.36.6-1.el7.ius               git236-core-doc.noarch 0:2.36.6-1.el7.ius               git236-perl-Git.noarch 0:2.36.6-1.el7.ius               pcre2.x86_64 0:10.23-2.el7              

Finished Transaction
> quit
Leaving Shell
```

Check/validate git version after upgrade.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.36.6
```

Comment: It would be more helpful to others if you could separate the comands from the outputs

Answer (score -3):

It can be very confusing, and dangerous, to replace the upstream base repositories with add-on repositories without considerable testing and thought. RPMforge, in particularly, is effectively moribund and is not getting updates.

I personally publish tools for building git 2.4, wrapped as an alternatively named "git24" package, at https://github.com/nkadel/git24-srpm/. Feel free to access and fork those if you want packages distinguished from the standard system packages, much as "samba" and "samba4" packages are differentiated.

Comment: It is okay to link to your own resources/websites at times, but please make sure your post still provides a sufficiently complete answer even if your link did not work (incidentally, it already doesn't work)