# How to update GIT version on CentOs 6?

Tags: git, github, centos, bitbucket

Every operation i try to do on my server related to git gives me this error

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing https://xxxx.org/proj/proj.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

So researching a bit i thought of updating my git. Currently my **git version is 1.7.1** But the problem is i can't find a proper way to update my git version on my **centos 6.8**

I referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21820715/4394926) but did not try it as the anwers are very old and rpmforge repo is not updated since a long time. Everything else seems not so promising.

A similar question to mine is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30288098/4394926) but unfortunately there is no solution in it and leads me to same link i shared.

Will updating the git solve my problem?
If yes the what is the right way to update git?If no then how to solve that error?

Comment: for git update try to follow the steps in the link : https://tecadmin.net/install-git-2-0-on-centos-rhel-fedora/#  and change the git version

Comment: About updating when you don't have install privileges :
You could just `git clone` git itself with the /usr/lib/git of version 1.7.1. Build it with `--prefix=$HOME`, install it and add $HOME/bin in the head of your PATH variable. This is what I've done here :-)

Here the 1.7.1 works quite well. So my guess is the problem is not on the version.

Is this not a proxy problem ?

Comment: @basslo `echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin" >> /etc/bashrc` gives me a error `-bash: /etc/bashrc: Permission denied` how to solve this?

Comment: @LaurentG I am not sure about it. But i tried doing `git clone` in my directory and it still gave me that error.

Comment: i didn't put it on /usr/local but $HOME since i don't have rights on /user/local

Comment: Uh uh. 401 is privilege problem. Did you give any "secret" to git in order to give him access to the remote repo ?

Comment: Can you verify the install put anything in $HOME/bin called git _something_ ?

Comment: i explicitly gave permissions to `/etc/bashrc` and installed the latest of git version 2.0.5 but now when i return back and run the git pull command i get `error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied` and if i use sudo then `sudo: git: command not found`

Comment: I have put it in /usr/local instead of $HOME so when i run `which git` it gives me `/usr/local/git/bin/git`