# Does 'yum git remove' on an active Git Server destroy any existing repo or config data?

Tags: git, centos

The Git server is already in use and runs on CentOS 6 with the default Git version 1.7.1. This is the latest version available via yum.

I wish to update Git to a newer version.

This can be done using Pytry's answer ( [How to install latest version of git on CentOS 6.x/7.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820715/how-to-install-latest-version-of-git-on-centos-6-x-7-x) ) to fetch the source code and build a later version.

However, to use the later version, the existing version must first be removed: $ yum remove git.

Since this is the Git server, my concern is whether removing the existing Git will this destroy any of the configuration data for the repos already resident on the server.

Comment: No, short of the package being **horrifically** broken you will not lose any data.

Answer (score 0):

No, your repos would be fine.

I suggest you to backup your .gitconfig file because sometimes you may have something important in it, such as your global name, email, and proxy.

By the way, there is a easier way to install newer version git, v1.7.12.

If you don't need git version 2.x, you can read this post: [Update your Git on CentOS 6.x](http://segmentfault.com/a/1190000002729908)

Comment: The package will not own any user's `.gitconfig` file any more than it will own the repository data.