# Configure git with Jenkins on Centos

Tags: git, plugins, jenkins, centos

I am trying to configure Jenkins on CentOS VM. I have already tried it on Windows and become successful. 
But on CentOS i can't run it. It shows the problems related to git. 
[image]
 The problem can be in git installation on Jenkins. Here is my configuration.

[image]

My console

[image]
Can anyone give me a solution of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default path for [Git on CentOS](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-the-latest-git-version-on-centos) should be:

```
/usr/local/git/bin
```

You will find the same installation process (and same path) in [this blog post](http://tecadmin.net/install-git-2-0-on-centos-rhel-fedora/).

More generally, if you have access to the CentOS VM, do a

```
which git
```

to see where it is installed.

Note that the warning you see "Installed git version too old for credentials support" would mean that:

- you have the right path for git (it is found and executed)
- but the installed version is too old: make sure to **[upgrade to the latest git available](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21820715/6309)** (by [recompiling the sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21820716/6309)).

Comment: Unknown option: -version
usage: git [--version] [--exec-path[=GIT_EXEC_PATH]] [--html-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects]
           [--bare] [--git-dir=GIT_DIR] [--work-tree=GIT_WORK_TREE]
           [--help] COMMAND [ARGS]

Comment: @Asif `-version` is not an option: `--version` is

Comment: it will be git --version

Comment: Yes.  And it successfully  build my gradle project. Thank you so much.