# Is there a yum resource of git's new version anywhere?

Tags: git, centos7

I am using centos7.2,when running `yum list git` ,it shows:

[image]

I would like to install a new version of git,is there a yum resource anywhere?

The result of `yum whatprovides git` is:

```
[root@i001 ~]# yum whatprovides git
Loaded plugins: axelget, langpacks
No metadata available for base
No metadata available for dockerrepo
No metadata available for elrepo
No metadata available for epel
No metadata available for extras
No metadata available for mariadb
No metadata available for nginx
No metadata available for remi
No metadata available for remi-php70
No metadata available for remi-php70-test
No metadata available for remi-safe
No metadata available for remi-test
No metadata available for salt-2015.8
No metadata available for updates
git-1.8.3.1-5.el7.x86_64 : Fast Version Control System
Repo        : base



git-1.8.3.1-6.el7.x86_64 : Fast Version Control System
Repo        : updates



git-1.8.3.1-6.el7_2.1.x86_64 : Fast Version Control System
Repo        : updates



git-1.8.3.1-6.el7.x86_64 : Fast Version Control System
Repo        : @updates
```

Comment: try: `sudo yum whatprovides git`. It will show you available rpms..

Comment: @ItayB what should I do next?

Comment: looks like you have the newest version available (for your rpm repos list). Are you looking for a specific version?

Comment: You can download a specific version here: https://github.com/git/git/releases

Comment: @ItayB It's source code,is there a yum resource anywhere?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820715/how-to-install-latest-version-of-git-on-centos-6-x-7-x