# Can't clone any repository using git

Tags: git, centos

I tried cloning a few repositories, but always get the same error. Where can I find some more information about this error (an error log file or something similar) or maybe someone knows what can be wrong?

```
# git clone http://github.com/creationix/nvm.git .nvm
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/marcin/.nvm/.git/
error:  while accessing http://github.com/creationix/nvm.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

or

```
# git clone https://gitlab.com/jmis/exilecraft.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/marcin/exilecraft/.git/
error:  while accessing https://gitlab.com/jmis/exilecraft.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I'm using CentOS 6.8 and Git 1.7.1

---------- EDIT
after upgrade Git to 2.12.0 I have error message:

```
# git clone https://github.com/creationix/nvm.git .nvm
Cloning into '.nvm'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/creationix/nvm.git/': Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

Comment: As a data point, using git 1.7.1 under CentOS 6.8, I can clone the second URL without a problem, and I can clone the first URL if I change `http://` to `https://`.  The problem goes away completely if I use a newer version of `git`.

Comment: I try update git to latest release but `git clone` doesn't work for me :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error is clearly described in [HTTPS cloning errors](https://help.github.com/articles/https-cloning-errors/)

Depending on the exact error message, trying to clone with your username in the url can help:

```
git clone https://<username>@github.com/<username>/<repo.git>
```

But ideally, you should [recompile and install a more recent version of Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26706653/6309).

With Git version 2.12.0, the error message is:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/creationix/nvm.git/': 
Problem with the SSL CA cert
```

Make sure you have installed the certificates:

```
sudo yum reinstall openssl ca-certificates -y
```

The manual version of this fix is:

```
mkdir -p /etc/pki/tls/certs
curl https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /etc/pki/tls/ca-bundle.crt
git config --global http.sslcainfo /etc/pki/tls/ca-bundle.crt
git config -l
```

Another [approach is described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/346756/7490):

```
mkdir /usr/src/ca-certificates && cd /usr/src/ca-certificates
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/ca-certificates-2015.2.6-65.0.1.el6_7.noarch.rpm
rpm2cpio ca-certificates-2015.2.6-65.0.1.el6_7.noarch.rpm | cpio -idmv
cp -pi ./etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.* /etc/pki/tls/certs/
```

---

Note: [edtech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187553/edtech) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42447538/cant-clone-any-repository-using-git/42448428#comment86374871_42448428):

> Upgrading the `nss` package ( `yum update nss` ) has solved the same problem for me.

Comment: using my github username I get `fatal: HTTP request failed`, now I try to recompile Git

Comment: @MastaBot you mention in your top comment having updated git to the latest relase though. What error message did you get?

Comment: now I have Git version 2.12.0 and still have error, now error message is `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/creationix/nvm.git/': Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)`

Comment: @MastaBot maybe you don't have those certificates, see my edited answer

Comment: Is `yum reinstall ca-certificates` safe for my working apache with SSL?

Comment: @MastaBot Then try the manual version (see edited answer): you can curl those certificates in any path you want (in case /etc/pki/tls/ca-bundle.crt already exist)

Comment: heh :/ git error `error: could not lock config file /usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig: No such file or directory` when try `git config --system http.sslcainfo /etc/pki/tls/ca-bundle.crt`  now I try to "First-Time Git Setup"

Comment: @MastaBot replace `--system` by `--global` in the `git config` command. I have edited my answer

Comment: still `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/creationix/nvm.git/': Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)` for sure I `rm /etc/pki/tls/ca-bundle.crt` and curl it again

Comment: @MastaBot OK, I have added another possible solution

Comment: still same error `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/creationix/nvm.git/': Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)` :(

Comment: @MastaBot did you check the rights associated with `/etc/pki/tls/ca-bundle.crt`? Can your current user access/read that file?

Comment: sure, all things above I do as root, then I can modify/remove etc ca-bundle.crt file

Comment: @MastaBot But your git command is not done as root, so the question is: can you access it from your current user.

Comment: Ok, I see where is problem :/ when I open  `/etc/pki/tls/ca-bundle.crt` with my editor then I see inside info `Resource is gone` you give me outdated url the correct one is `https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem` any way you help me a lot, thanks! Pls edit your answer to correct this link.

Comment: @MastaBot Great. I have updated the answer with the right url.

Comment: Upgrading the nss package ( `yum update nss` ) has solved the same problem for me

Comment: @edtech Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

There can be a variety of reasons (proxy, firewall, company policy and more).
As far as i know github has removed the support for the **`http`** and now only support **`https`**

Change the protocol to ssh and it will work without any problems.

There is a very detailed document on how to do it.
https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

To summarize it:

- Generate ssh key locally
  open git-bash/terminal and generate the key `ssh-keygen`
- Copy the key `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
- open git hub ans paste the key under your profile settings
- Clone with the ssh url instead of the http/https.

---

Login to your github account

- In the upper-right corner of any page, click your profile photo, then click  **Settings**.

[image]

- In the user settings sidebar, click **SSH and GPG keys**

[image].

- Click **New SSH key** or **Add SSH key**.

[image]

- Paste your key into the **Key** field.

[image]

- Click **Add SSH key**.

[image]

- If prompted, confirm your GitHub password.

[image]

Comment: after adding SSH Key on github I still get same error

Comment: Are you contributor to the project? if its a private repo you must be contributor to clone it.

Comment: I only want update my nvm (node version manager) and all (or many instruction how to do it start with `git clone http://github.com/creationix/nvm.git`

Comment: You can also install it like this: `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.1/install.sh | bash`

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting "SSL connect error" try to update nss and curl.

For example on CentOS:

> yum update -y nss curl