# How do I install the latest GIT and SVN on CentOS 7?

Tags: git, svn, centos

([Already solved, posting for the next guy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/))

I am working on setting up a Git and Subversion server running off CentOS 7.

To install Git and Subversion I ran

`yum install git`

and

`yum install subversion`

This worked, but for both it gave me currently unsupported versions (SVN 1.7.14, Git 1.8.3.1)

I found this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820715/how-to-install-latest-version-of-git-on-centos-6-x-7-x) which discusses installing the 'latest' git, but the question is quite old and convoluted.

I've also found sources on how to compile it myself, but I'm not comfortable doing that and it appears to interact weird with yum in the future.

So, how can I install the newest versions of both? The simpler the solution the better.

Comment: Why the downvote? It isn't useful without any explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I have found is to tell yum where to look for the new versions.
To do this, you need to create a .repo file for yum

On my system this involved:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
vim wandisco.repo
```

In the new file put the text:

> [WandiscoSVN]
>   name=Wandisco SVN Repo
>   baseurl=http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/7/svn-1.9/RPMS/$basearch/
>   enabled=1
>   gpgcheck=1
>   gpgkey=http://opensource.wandisco.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-WANdisco
>
> [WandiscoGIT]
>   name=Wandisco GIT Repo
>   baseurl=http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/7/git/$basearch/
>   enabled=1
>   gpgcheck=1
>   gpgkey=http://opensource.wandisco.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-WANdisco

This will direct yum to look to the WANdisco servers when you are attempting to install things.
Then run

```
yum install git subversion
```

and they should both update to the most recent versions