# stderr: fatal: cannot exec '/tmp/ssh**.sh': Permission denied fatal: unable to fork

Tags: git, jenkins, github, continuous-integration

I am seeing an error while trying to execute Jenkins job.

git version 1.8.3.1
Jenkins 2.46.2.1-rolling

I tried upgrading git to a higher version but still, it hangs with 1.8.3.1 by following [How to install latest version of git on CentOS 6.x/7.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820715/how-to-install-latest-version-of-git-on-centos-6-x-7-x) link.Giving permissions to /tmp also did not work

My RHEL7 server is from AWS.

Error Logs while building Jenkins job-

```
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@git.devops.company.net:user/project_test.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@git.devops.company.net:user/project_test.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@git.devops.company.net:user/project_test.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@git.devops.company.net:user/project_test.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:806)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1070)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1101)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:109)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:73)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:260)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress git@git.devops.company.net:user/project_test.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: cannot exec '/tmp/ssh2653538317929125933.sh': Permission denied
fatal: unable to fork

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1793)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1519)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:64)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:315)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at ......remote call to zz_server_IP(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1545)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:253)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:830)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1953.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:132)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140.execute(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:804)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 2):

The Jenkins git client plugin uses a file in a temporary directory to pass credentials to command line git.  If the selected temporary directory is mounted with the `noexec` option, then command line git is not allowed to execute the script from the temporary directory.  The `git fetch` will fail with a stack trace because command line git did not receive the required credentials.

Git client plugin versions since 2.4.4 (released April 24, 2017) attempt to use a temporary directory within the Jenkins job environment.  The system temporary directory is used if a Jenkins job environment is not available.

Alternatives to solve the problem include:

- Declare a different system temporary directory in the script that starts Jenkins (whether /etc/init.d or Windows or shell script): `java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/tmpdir jenkins.war`
- Declare a different temporary directory for Jenkins ssh agents as a JVM option configured in the "Advanced" section of the agent: `-Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/tmpdir`
- Declare a different temporary directory of Jenkins JNLP agents as a JVM option on the command line that starts the JNLP agent: `java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/tmpdir agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://jenkins.example.com:8080/computer/my-agent/slave-agent.jnlp -secret MY-SECRET`
- Use the [JGit implementation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-client-plugin#enabling-jgit) in the Jenkins git client plugin instead of command line git
- Mount the system temporary file system without the `noexec` option