# Flutter version Unknown

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Hi after installing flutter on our CI-Server I got the following message:

`...
[Setup Flutter Android] [✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.0.0-unknown, on Linux, locale en_US)
...`

had some already the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem on CentOS.
It turns out that the default git installed in CentOs is too out-of-dated.

Please try upgrading git to the latest version on CentOS by following this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27674776/7179304) and then run `flutter doctor` again

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this problem on CentOS 7. [This comment on github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15385#issuecomment-390952672) explains it.

It happens with git versions before v1.8.4 because of "git describe --first-parent" not being implemented in older versions. As for CentOS 7, newest git version that you can get using yum is unfortunately v1.8.3.1.

TL;DR use something like [ius](https://ius.io) to get a newer git version.