# git upgrade in RHEL 7.4

Tags: linux, git, github, gitlab

My git version is 1.8.3.1 and require to upgrade the latest version.

For that, do I need to follow any additional steps or installation enough?
Will it be affect my projects, groups and user management?

Answer (score 0):

> for that do I need to follow any additional steps or installation enough,

The installation ([`yum install` as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21820716/6309)) is enough.

> will it be affect my projects, groups and user management.

No, Git does not manage groups/users.