# yum installs an older version of git on Centos

Tags: git, centos

When I install git on windows or Ubuntu, i get a recent version of git close to what is listed here:

https://github.com/git/git/releases

However, When I install git  on a centos Linux, I get an older version of git:

```
yum check-update

yum install -y git

git --version

git version 1.8.3.1
```

version 1.8.3.1 is to old. I think I am missing something here.

Why do I get such old version of git on centos?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27674776/6064025

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to first install the wandisco repository and then update git.

Use your centos version in the URL.

`yum install http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/7/git/x86_64/wandisco-git-release-7-2.noarch.rpm`

`yum update git`

Comment: it worked, thank you. Do you know why it is not documented here: https://git-scm.com/download/linux

Comment: While it's highly unlikely that a newer `git` will cause any trouble, there is a reason why things are older in CentOS - stability. Everything is built in harmony ensuring packages depending on each other work without any issues together.