# An issue with using Git with http proxy on CentOS. Http request failed

Tags: git, proxy, centos

I have an issue with

```
git clone https://github.com/off-border/QtXMLMap.git
```

or

```
git clone http://github.com/off-border/QtXMLMap.git
```

via http/https proxy on CentOS

i've setted the environment variables:

```
export http_proxy=http://myproxy:port
export https_proxy=http://myproxy:port
export HTTP_PROXY=http://myproxy:port
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://myproxy:port
```

i also setted the git config variables:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://myproxy:port
git config --global https.proxy http://myproxy:port
```

And had the same result after an 3-5 minutes all the time:

```
    Cloning into 'QtXMLMap'...
error: Empty reply from server while accessing https://github.com/off-border/QtXMLMap.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Wget works fine. Git clone does not work.

Comment: i've found one solution: rollback to older git:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429416/git-clone-timed-out-when-used-through-https-proxy

but i'm not an admin on the server :(

Comment: You can also check the awesome post from @AmirHD here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21820716/1049572